# Unable to connect Excel to ALM

Tags: excel, vba, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

Trying to connect to HP ALM 12.5 from Excel using below code

```
qcURL = "https://xxx-alm.xxxx.com/qcbin"
qcID = "xxxxx"
qcPWD = "xxxx"
qcDomain = "xxxO"
qcProject = "xxxxxx"

'Initiate connection with ALM Server
Set oTDConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
oTDConnection.InitConnection qcURL, qcDomain
oTDConnection.ConnectProject qcProject, qcID, qcPWD
Set com = oTDConnection.Command
```

and have referenced below libraries:
[image]

If i try to run I get an error as below on the line

```
Set oTDConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
```

[image]

I tried with various solutions provided in forums like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213496/how-do-i-resolve-run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object), [here](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/ALM-QC-User-Discussions/Connecting-to-QC-via-IIS/td-p/1049080), and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/468f1359-2b65-46d8-b3aa-bc5e4c92136b/error-2147221164-class-not-registered-access-vba?forum=accessdev) but could not resolve

Comment: https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/registration-of-64-bit-activex-controls

Answer (score 0):

Install HP ALM Client on your machine, it is available on your ALM server: http://almserver:8080/qcbin/start_a.jsp?common=true

Answer (score 0):

OTA is a 32-bit COM library, you cannot use it in 64bit Office. From your screenshot, you've already had OTA Client registered in your computer, otherwise you can't see it in the "References" dialog. So, probably, you're using 64 bit Excel to invoke OTA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).